# Issue regarding JWT token and CORS in Spring and React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, cookies, cross-domain

I am trying to create a spring boot application that uses a token authentication method. I wanted to go easy so I used this repo https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-login-example-mysql/ as inspiration. No SQL problems. My code is exactly the same as that one there.

When I am doing requests in POSTMAN everything works fine and nothing is wrong.
When I am doing a request in the front end, I get a CORS error that I miss a header or some sort. I fixed that by adding the following class in the project

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    }
}
```

At that point, I get the `set-cookie` header with the correct value, but the cookie is not set. I have also added the `withCredentials: true` in the header request in AXIOS. Can someone explain to me what is going on and show a solution to this problem using React as frontend?

Many thanks!

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i

Comment: @IrfanullahJan thanks for the reply, but the headers are fine. The cookie is not setting up.

Answer (score 0):

use this and see whether it works or not make sure to create a different java class and in your application.properties write app.client.url="localhost your url"

```
@Component
```

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

```
@Value("${app.client.url}")
private String clientAppUrl = "";

public SimpleCorsFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String originHeader = request.getHeader("origin");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}